# How to pass data from one controller to another in laravel

Tags: php, database, controller, laravel-5

I am retrieving data from database in one controller. I want to pass this data to another controller in laravel.

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: Using session, query string etc.

Comment: Actually i want to build a social network in laravel. I want to make it in modules so that user can easily add modules whenever he want. I want to pass variable from plugin class to main controller.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like this:

```
return Redirect::action('AnotherController@function')
->with('data',$data);
```

Comment: This is a kind of loop. I dont want this.

Comment: Actually i want to build a social network in laravel. I want to make it in modules so that user can easily add modules whenever he want. I want to pass variable from plugin class to main controller.

Comment: i guess `Love to Code` is just a name. Show us you work mate and would be able to help ;)